# Is there any greedy solution for bitonic tour

Tags: greedy-algorithms

I have found dynamic solution for [Bitonic tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour) but I could not find any greedy approach for this problem. Is it possible to solve it in a greedy manner?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't mention one, but does mention dynamic programming.